# looping through object values and formatting a array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a results from web service is:

```
[  
  {  
    "spId":"SmTest_W1_Rf",
    "type":"sp",
    "latitude":32.816711,
    "longitude":-117.25,
    "spVolume":403.58157286047935,
    "isInFlow":false,
    "address":null,
    "events":[  
      {  
        "eventName":"Leak",
        "startDate":20140215,
        "endDate":20140221,
        "noOfDays":7,
        "eventVolume":86.62499237060547
      },
      {  
        "eventName":"Leak",
        "startDate":20140223,
        "endDate":20140301,
        "noOfDays":7,
        "eventVolume":44.916664123535156
      },
      {  
        "eventName":"ReverseFlow",
        "startDate":20140204,
        "endDate":20140204,
        "noOfDays":1,
        "eventVolume":-1.6041665077209473
      },
      {  
        "eventName":"UsageInactive",
        "startDate":20140204,
        "endDate":20140205,
        "noOfDays":2,
        "eventVolume":3.609374761581421
      },
      {  
        "eventName":"UsageInactive",
        "startDate":20140208,
        "endDate":20140306,
        "noOfDays":27,
        "eventVolume":533.6527709960938
      }
    ]
  },
  {  
    "spId":"SmTest_NPW1_Rf",
    "type":"sp",
    "latitude":32.816711,
    "longitude":-117.25,
    "spVolume":8983.332550048828,
    "isInFlow":false,
    "address":null,
    "events":[  
      {  
        "eventName":"Leak",
        "startDate":20121231,
        "endDate":20141027,
        "noOfDays":666,
        "eventVolume":213674.984375
      },
      {  
        "eventName":"UsageInactive",
        "startDate":20121231,
        "endDate":20141027,
        "noOfDays":666,
        "eventVolume":213340.78125
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And Expected result is like this : (Not same but format will be same)

```
[  
  {  
    "servicePoint":"67410074",
    "isInFlow":0,
    "eventType":"Reverse Flow",
    "startDay":"201111010100",
    "endDay":"201501050100",
    "volume":10,
    "noOfdays":5
  },
  {  
    "servicePoint":"67410074",
    "isInFlow":0,
    "eventType":"Metered Leaks",
    "startDay":"201211010100",
    "endDay":"201401050100",
    "volume":9,
    "noOfdays":3
  },
  {  
    "servicePoint":"67410074",
    "isInFlow":0,
    "eventType":"Tamper",
    "startDay":"201311010100",
    "endDay":"201401050100",
    "volume":12,
    "noOfdays":8
  }
]
```

My code :

```
var popUpDetailsData = [];
var eventGridDetailsData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
    if (gridData[i].events.length !== 0) {
        eventGridDetailsData.servicePoint = gridData[i].spId;
        eventGridDetailsData.isInFlow = gridData[i].isInFlow;
        for (var j = 0; j < gridData[i].events.length; j++) {
            eventGridDetailsData.eventType = gridData[i].events[j].eventName;
            eventGridDetailsData.startDay = gridData[i].events[j].startDate;
            eventGridDetailsData.endDay = gridData[i].events[j].endDate;
            eventGridDetailsData.volume = gridData[i].events[j].eventVolume;
            eventGridDetailsData.noOfdays = gridData[i].events[j].noOfDays;
            popUpDetailsData.push(eventGridDetailsData);
        }
    }
}

var popUpDetailsData = popUpDetailsData;
```

[image]
I am getting repeating array values.. I mean same array values.
Please help me.. where I am doing wrong..

Comment: You defined " var eventGridDetailsData=[]", however, you use it as an object "eventGridDetailsData.servicePoint = gridData[i].spId".

Comment: Not really useful showing us some source data and then using some different source data for your expected result. And how are we supposed to read the output on that screenshot? A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would have also been nice.

Comment: @Xotic750 yea I thought the same for the image just right click and open in image in new tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the position of the initialization of your variables.

[I've fiddled around with it](http://jsfiddle.net/exsymaxr/) and came to this piece of code:

```
var popUpDetailsData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
    if (gridData[i].events.length !== 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < gridData[i].events.length; j++) {
            var eventGridDetailsData = [];
            eventGridDetailsData.servicePoint = gridData[i].spId;
            eventGridDetailsData.isInFlow = gridData[i].isInFlow;
            eventGridDetailsData.eventType = gridData[i].events[j].eventName;
            eventGridDetailsData.startDay = gridData[i].events[j].startDate;
            eventGridDetailsData.endDay = gridData[i].events[j].endDate;
            eventGridDetailsData.volume = gridData[i].events[j].eventVolume;
            eventGridDetailsData.noOfdays = gridData[i].events[j].noOfDays;
            popUpDetailsData.push(eventGridDetailsData);
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see, I've placed the `var eventGridDetailsData` inside the second for loop. This is because we want an CLEAR array object every time ( no leftovers of the previous time ).

Same for the `servicePoint and isInFlow`, but that is because the variable is placed later on, so these lines also had to be placed later on...

Comment: This is a good learning for me.. I really missed it.. Thanks +1.. Accepted

Answer (score 1):

An example using ECMA5 methods.

```js
var gridData = [  
  {  
    "spId":"SmTest_W1_Rf",
    "type":"sp",
    "latitude":32.816711,
    "longitude":-117.25,
    "spVolume":403.58157286047935,
    "isInFlow":false,
    "address":null,
    "events":[  
      {  
        "eventName":"Leak",
        "startDate":20140215,
        "endDate":20140221,
        "noOfDays":7,
        "eventVolume":86.62499237060547
      },
      {  
        "eventName":"Leak",
        "startDate":20140223,
        "endDate":20140301,
        "noOfDays":7,
        "eventVolume":44.916664123535156
      },
      {  
        "eventName":"ReverseFlow",
        "startDate":20140204,
        "endDate":20140204,
        "noOfDays":1,
        "eventVolume":-1.6041665077209473
      },
      {  
        "eventName":"UsageInactive",
        "startDate":20140204,
        "endDate":20140205,
        "noOfDays":2,
        "eventVolume":3.609374761581421
      },
      {  
        "eventName":"UsageInactive",
        "startDate":20140208,
        "endDate":20140306,
        "noOfDays":27,
        "eventVolume":533.6527709960938
      }
    ]
  },
  {  
    "spId":"SmTest_NPW1_Rf",
    "type":"sp",
    "latitude":32.816711,
    "longitude":-117.25,
    "spVolume":8983.332550048828,
    "isInFlow":false,
    "address":null,
    "events":[  
      {  
        "eventName":"Leak",
        "startDate":20121231,
        "endDate":20141027,
        "noOfDays":666,
        "eventVolume":213674.984375
      },
      {  
        "eventName":"UsageInactive",
        "startDate":20121231,
        "endDate":20141027,
        "noOfDays":666,
        "eventVolume":213340.78125
      }
    ]
  }
];

var popUpDetailsData = gridData.reduce(function (accumulate, item) {
    item.events.forEach(function (event) {
        accumulate.push({
            servicePoint: this.spId,
            isInFlow: this.isInFlow,
            eventType: event.eventName,
            startDay: event.startDate,
            endDay: event.endDate,
            volume: event.eventVolume,
            noOfdays: event.noOfDays
        });
    }, item);
    
    return accumulate;
}, []);


document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(popUpDetailsData, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```